# C++ Memory Cleanup of Dynamic Cast Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-cast

I've tried googling around but haven't been able to find a direct answer to a simple question involving the cleanup of memory for dynamic casted pointers.

Do you have to deallocate/cleanup a pointer that has been dynamically casted in C++ or is it automatically cleaned up by the compiler etc.?

e.g.

```
BaseType* obj;
DerivedType* mrPointer = dynamic_cast<DerivedType*>(obj);
//Code happens here
//At the end up the use of mrPointer
mrPointer = nullptr;  //Is this necessary/Is there a more proper way to cleanup?
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't free pointers; you free the objects pointed to by pointers.

Comment: The actual objects which are declared with 'new' keywords right? Would have to use delete on those. But all of these pointers (in the example) wouldn't have to be free'd if OBJ was just pointing to the real OBJ location

Comment: In this chunk of code you don't free any previously allocated memory. A pointer is just a number, a record with an address of memory. So assigning a null to a pointer simply rewrites that number, leaving the memory it pointed to unchanged, but perhaps inaccessible (you don't know the address anymore). Dynamic cast also doesn't allocate memory, it simply allows to re-interpret an existing previously allocated memory chunk corresponding to an "object"

Comment: Yeah, I realized I was just getting confused over normal Pointers and dynamic pointers, Thanks!

Comment: casting has nothing to do with memory allocation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about your concerns,
but in your example line:

```
mrPointer = nullptr;
```

does nothing except assigning `nullptr` to `mrPointer` and unnecessary here.

and please use `std::shared_ptr` better - it will help you manage memory.
To cast `shared_ptr` use `std::static_pointer_cast`, `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` and `std::const_pointer_cast`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to free no longer used resources, like for example the objects pointer to by a pointer, in your case dynamically cast, you **either** use the `delete` operator and place the no longer used pointer after it, i.e.:

```
delete mrPointer;
```

**or** you could use smart pointers like [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), whose object is destroyed and its memory deallocated automatically, under specific circumstances.

If your pointer will own only a single object throughout its lifetime you could use [`unique_ptr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279674.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), that again will take care of the resource management for you.

---

### Note:

dynamic cast is used to interpret raw memory addresses to specific type and should not affect your view on memory resource management, i.e. the memory pointed to by the pointer should be free when is no longer needed, regardless if the pointer points to already known type of memory or to a type that you make it interpret, using [explicit type conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast).